# How would I construct an EMI shield for low frequency EMI?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

By low frequency, I mean 30-100 Hz. Would a Faraday cage or something like it be feasible? I am trying to shield two separate locations on a high voltage cable.

Comment: A cookie jar or paint jar works very well for most cases, unless your EMI is strong magnetic fields, then you will need significant amounts of iron or soft steel. If you need to shield a cable, put it in galvanized steel pipe from the hardware store.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the EMI is not that strong in this range. Maximum coupling is through wires and ground lifting is a major cause of it. I can suggest you to use different "Dedicated grounds" for each high voltage if the situation is siviour. Usually this can be solved by improving the grounding circuit i.e. connect each circuit to ground separately rather than connecting them to a board then one wire from board connects to ground. Ground should be dedicated to the lab and not connected to the common ground of the electricity (which is rather low quality).

Dedicated grounds are made by making hole in earth and putting some salt coal etc and then putting a thick copper wire in the earth, above the ground a thick aluminum strip is circulated through the lab connected with that copper wire. Low resistance is the key to make a good ground.

[image]

Another thing that is usually used to decouple HV from sensitive equipment is to use optocoupler and inductive decoupling (using transformers or Tesla coils).

If you have EMI from discharges or firing of capacitor banks you have to use Faraday cage.

I hope this will help